# Как отнять здоровье у врага через UnityEvent?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не работает UnityEvent должным образом. (Ну или я чего-то не пойму). Есть враги, и я хочу через UnityEvent убавлять им здоровье, если игрок точкой атаки попадает по колайдеру врага.
Сделал вот такой код у игрока:

```
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _enemyLayers;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _attackPoint;
    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent<int, Collider2D> _hitEnemy;

    [SerializeField] private float _rangeHit = 0.2f;

    private int _hitDamage = 20;



    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Attack();
        }
    }

    private void Attack()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(_attackPoint.position, _rangeHit, _enemyLayers);

        foreach (Collider2D collider in colliders)
        {
            _hitEnemy?.Invoke(_hitDamage, collider);
            Debug.Log(collider);
        }
    }
```

Вот такой у врага:

```
    [SerializeField] private Collider2D _currentCollider;

    [SerializeField] private int _health = 100;


    public void TakeDamage(int damage, Collider2D collider)
    {
        if (collider == _currentCollider)
            _health -= damage;

        if (_health <= 0)
            Die();
    }

    private void Die()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

В самом юнити указал объект врага и вызываемое действие.
Запускаю сцену, и после атаки ничего не происходит(здоровье у врага не убавляется).
Но когда заместо UnityEvent делаю  `public Action<int, Collider2D> _hitEnemy;` и в коде врага подписываюсь на событие и при смерти отписываюсь, всё работает нормально... Но я хотел бы, чтоб код врага не содержал ссылки на скрипт игрока, и решил запилить через UnityEvent.
И подскажите ещё, насколько колхозно я сделал атаку через событие и что можно изменить?

Comment: Зачем тебе здесь вообще ивенты, особенно юнитивские? Делаешь интерфейс `IDamageable`, реализуешь его у тех, кто должен получать урон. Когда атакуешь, делаешь то же самое, что и у тебя: overlapcircle, у коллайдеров пытаешься получить компонент `IDamageable` (`collider.TryGetComponent(out IDamageable damageable)`) и наносишь урон  - `damageable.ApplyDamage(damage)`. Всё. Не нужны здесь никакие ивенты, все решается одним интерфейсом.

Comment: @KOTlK да, была мысль сделать так, даже как-то сделал, но без реализации интерфеса, просто через скрипт атаки `colider.TryGetComponent(out PlayerAttack playerAttack)`. Хорошо, сделаю так, спасибо :)
И ещё пару вопросов, в каких тогда случаях использовать события? Если например захочу подбирать предметы и добавлять здоровье у игрока или просто в инвентарь класть, подойдут?

Comment: Для всего того, что ты перечислил, нужны интерфейсы. Делаешь IPickableItem и реализуешь его у предметов, здоровья и т.д. События нужны, когда хочешь отследить что-то. Изменение переменной или ожидание действия. Допустим, нужно при смерти игрока выводить на экран что-нибудь. У игрока создаем ивент Died, подписываем на этот ивент метод, который выводит на экран надпись. Вызываем ивент, когда игрок умирает. Все методы, которые подписаны на ивент вызовутся, когда вызовется ивент. События - это реализация паттерна Observer в языке. Хочешь понять для чего они нужны, смотри для чего нужен observer.

Comment: @KOTlK Понял, спасибо.